# How to write your own condition variable using atomic primitives

Tags: c++

I need to write my own implementation of a condition variable much like pthread_cond_t.

I know I'll need to use the compiler provided primitives like __sync_val_compare_and_swap etc.

Does anyone know how I'd go about this please.

Thx

Comment: And you somehow don't think the target platform is in any way relevant?

Comment: @John: nor the compiler apparently, though I guess the two go hand in hand. @ScaryAardvark: have you tried a library before saying that you NEED to implement it ?

Comment: As a note, if you can't use operating system mutexes/events/conditions/whatever, you will not be able to implement this any way that's efficient. What OS are you on, and what can you use - except a pthread_cond_t ?

Comment: a good start might be this: http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

Comment: @stefaanv: According to ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/sources/pthreads-w32-2-8-0-release/pthread_cond_init.c , pthreads-win32 just implements this in terms of critical sections.

Comment: @Matthieu:  Apparently, it's a compiler that provides `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` as a primitive.  Since I'm fairly sure that isn't in the Standard, there really isn't a satisfactory answer to this question without more information.

Comment: Multithreading is hard to get right even with support from existing proven libraries. Think twice whether you want to build your own library, you might end up in a mess of a project where you cannot even diagnose if the problem is in the multi-threaded code or the threading primitives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct implementation of condition variables is **HARD**. Use one of the many libraries out there instead (e.g. boost, pthreads-win32, my just::thread library)

You need to:

- Keep a list of waiting threads (this might be a "virtual" list rather than an actual data structure)
- Ensure that when a thread waits you **atomically** unlock the mutex owned by the waiting thread and add it to the list before that thread goes into a blocking OS call
- Ensure that when the condition variable is notified then one of the threads waiting at that time is woken, and not one that waits later
- Ensure that when the condition variable is broadcast then **all** of the threads waiting at that time are woken, and not any threads that wait later.
- plus other issues that I can't think of just now.

The details vary with OS, as you are dependent on the OS blocking/waking primitives.

Comment: It might be considered inappropriate to self-reference a product, so I understand you not linking it. But I am quite free to do so: [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/)

Comment: If you are dependant on OS blocking/waking primitives, you might as well just use those and not even bother reimplementing pthread_cond_t. Otherwise you'll have to resort to spin-locking/busy waiting in user space which is not going to be fun..

Answer (score 4):

> I need to write my own implementation of a condition variable much like pthread_cond_t.

The condition variables cannot be implemented using only the atomic primitives like [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

The purpose in life of the cond vars is to provide flexible mechanism for application to access the process/thread scheduler: put a thread into sleep and wake it up.

Atomic ops are implemented by the CPU, while process/thread scheduler is an OS territory. Without some supporting system call (or emulation using existing synchronization primitives) implementing cond vars is impossible.

*Edit1.* The only sensible example I know and can point you to is the implementation of the historical Linux pthread library which can be found [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/) - e.g. [version from 1997](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-linuxthreads-2.0.6.tar.gz). The implementation (found in condvar.c file) is rather easy to read but also highlights the requirements for implementation of the cond vars. [Spinlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) (using [test-and-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) op) are used for synchronizations and [POSIX signals](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) are used to put threads into sleep and to wake them up.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements. IF you have no further requirements, and if your process may consume 100% of available CPU time, then you have the **rare** chance to experiment and try out different mutex and condition variables - just try it out, and learn about the details. Great thing.

But in reality, you are uusally bound to an operating system, and so you are captivated on the OSs threading primitives, because they represent the only kind of control to - yeah - process/threading/cpu ressource usage! So, in that case, you will not even have the chance to implement your OWN condition variables - if they are not based on the primites, that the OS provides you!

So... double check your ***environment***, what do you control? What don't you control? And what makes sense?